# Is there a way to update global variables and private class variables from subscribe operators in RXJava (or am I doing RXJava wrong)?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm a total rookie in RXJava and I have a rather odd architecture for an Android activity because a lot of the activity has dependencies. For example, I need some weather data and that comes from OpenWeather, which is dependent on location services, etc. Then I need some data from another thing, and all of these get combined into doing a fancy calculation. I don't want to have a GIANT nested method to do all of these things, so I'm trying to use RXJava so that I only make a calculation when an event occurs, like a successful OpenWeather connection or something like that.

Here's my problem. I keep trying to update private variables in the class with data as it is observed, but the variables never update, staying at their default values.

```
...
 compositeDisposable.add(dataObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(data -> {
      mPrivateClassLevelData = data;
}));
```

I'm doing this (potentially completely misguided) as a way to try and update the mPrivateClassLevelData so that it's usable in other methods of the class. However, it doesn't work at all because the mPrivateClassLevelData always stays with the default value. Why is this and what is the best way to fix it? If I created another observable or something, how do I use it later in other methods?

Comment: Have you confirmed the code in your `onNext`  block is being called?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is because I had some stuff writing to external logs in the onNext block and the logs are updating as expected which leads me to believe it's being called.

Comment: In practice this is probably quite unlikely, but in theory, updating your variable from a thread pool (`io()` is a thread pool) could result in your variable being cached between threads and not read correctly. You should use the `volatile` keyword, or wrap it in an `AtomicReference`